# How to check if a list contains item in dynamic list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, dynamic

In a `dynamic` `List<XElement>` I want to get all the values that contains specific `attValue`.
To do that I'm using this:

```
return new DynamicXml(from item in _elements
                     where item.Attribute("attName").Value.Contains("attValue")
                     select item);
```

and To get attributes with more than one attribute value, I could use something like this:

```
return new DynamicXml(from item in _elements
                     where item.Attribute("attName").Value.Contains("attValue") ||
                           item.Attribute("attName").Value.Contains("attValue2")
                     select item);
```

all of the previous code works properly, now I'm trying to do the exact thing in the second code block, but instead of adding static conditions i need to pass a list that contains the attribute values, to get the values, but it returns wrong data.
I tried to do it like this:

1. This return all the value no matter what their attribute Values are.

   ```
   return new DynamicXml(from item in _elements
                        where attValues.Any(v => v.Contains(item.Value))
                        select item);
   ```
2. This do not return anything:

   ```
   return new DynamicXml(from item in _elements
                        where attValues.Contains(item.Value)
                        select item);
   ```

**Note:** attValues is List

**Edit:**

_`elements` contains properties like this:

```
<property name="id" xpath="//Atom:entry/Atom:id"  disAtt="" mediaType="txt,pix"  isSingleSelection="true" />
```

the `attValues` contains `mediaTypes`:
`"txt"` OR `"vid"` etc

I need to get all the `properties` that have `mediaType` of type `txt` or `vid`

**Note:** I can get the mediaType like this:

```
dynObject[0].property.mediaType.Value;
```

Comment: Could you show some example contents and creation of your attValues list please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks backwards, In the first example you want a specific attribute where it's value contains one of a list, In the second example you show code getting any attribute whose value is contained by one of your list.

Assuming attValues is a list of values to search for

```
return new DynamicXml(from item in _elements
                 where attValues.Any(v => item.Attribute("attName").Value.Contains(v))
                 select item);
```